# Create set of dictionaries from dictionary and list of lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of lists and a dictionary mapping names to ages:

```
listofl = [['ID', 'gender', 'ethnicity', 'name', 'address', 'children'], ['1', 'female', 'white', 'Amy', 'XXXX', '2'], ['2', 'male', 'white', 'Mark', 'XXXX', '0'], [...]]
d1 = {'AMY' : 52, 'JACK' : 39, 'MARK' : 74, 'MELISSA' : 29...}
```

Some of the keys are also included in the list of lists, along with other information of those people. I want to create a set of dictionaries in which, if a name is present in the sublists and in the dictionary, it becomes a key, to which there is a dictionary containing information about age, gender and ethnicity. So the outcome would need to be like this:

```
d2 = {'Amy' : {'age' : 52, 'gender' : 'female', 'ethnicity' : 'white'}, 'Mark' : {'age' : 74, 'gender' : 'male', 'ethnicity' : 'white'}, ...}
```

Or like this:

```
d2 = {'Amy' : ['age' : 52, 'gender' : 'female', 'ethnicity' : 'white'], 'Mark' : ['age' : 74, 'gender' : 'male', 'ethnicity' : 'white'], ...}
```

What I tried is:

```
d2 = {}
newk = ["age", "gender", "ethnicity"]
for key in d1.items():
    new_keys = []
    new_keys.append(key)
    for i in listofl[1:]:
        newv = []
        for k in i:
            if k[3].upper() in new_keys:
                newv.append(read.values())
                newv.append(k[1])
                newv.append(k[2])
        sub_d = dict(zip(newk, newv))
        d2 = dict(zip(key, sub_d))
print(d2)
```

But I just get a series of empty dictionaries. 
Also, how can I extract information from the new dictionary to analyse it? Just by using `for key, value in d2.items()` or do I need different syntax with sets of dictionaries? 
I'm new to Python so I don't know most of the packages and I tend to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Would also help to see what the list of lists looks like

Comment: please show what the `list of lists` looks like

Comment: I edited it to include the list of lists

Comment: @Mary Change to for `record in listofl[1:]: ; gender, ethnicity, name = record[1], record[2], record[3].upper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
import datetime

listofl = [['1', 'female', 'white', 'Amy', '03/10/1967', 'XXXX', '2'], ['2', 
'male', 'white', 'Mark', '01/07/1945', 'XXXX', '0']]
d1 = {'AMY' : 52, 'JACK' : 39, 'MARK' : 74, 'MELISSA' : 29}

for item in listofl :
    item[3] = item[3].upper()

d2 = {}
newk = ["age", "gender", "ethnicity"]
keys = d1.keys()


for item in listofl :
    for key in keys :
        dic={}
        if key in item :
            dic['age']=datetime.datetime.now().year-int(item[4][-4::])
            dic['gender']=item[1]
            dic['ethnicity']=item[2]
            d2[key] = dic

print(d2)
```

output:

```
{'AMY': {'age': 52, 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'white'}, 
'MARK': {'age': 74, 'gender': 'male', 'ethnicity': 'white'}}
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the age from the dictionary, like dic['age'] = d1.values()? Because the information is not available in the list of lists

Comment: I changed the code to solve the names problem

Comment: you can write dic['age'] = d1[key] instead of dic['age']=datetime.datetime.now().year-int(item[4][-4::])

Comment: so you can try this : dic['age'] = d1[key]  instead of dic['age']=datetime.datetime.now().year-int(item[4][-4::])

Comment: One more thing, so if now I want to retrieve all the 'gender' = 'female' based on 'ethnicity'='white', do I use keys and values in dic.items() as I would in a normal dictionary?